# SQL query to identify 0 AFTER a 1

Tags: sql, teradata

Let's say I have two columns: **Date** and **Indicator**

**Usually the indicator goes from 0 to 1** (when the data is sorted by date) and **I want to be able to identify if it goes from 1 to 0 instead**.  Is there an easy way to do this with SQL?

I am already aggregating other fields in the same table.  If I can add this to as another aggregation (e.g. without using a separate "where" statement or passing over the data a second time) it would be pretty awesome.

This is the phenomena I want to catch:

```
Date      Indicator
1/5/01    0
1/4/01    0
1/3/01    1
1/2/01    1
1/1/01    0
```

Comment: rejoin on the table 1 record ahead or behind and say `where A != B`

Comment: What do you mean by "goes from"?  Are you talking about row updates or about differences between similar rows?

Comment: Can you claify what you are asking? this could be a number of things

Comment: When I said "goes from" I said "when the data is sorted by date" as in day x it is 1 and day x+1 it is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a teradata-specific answer, but this *can* be done in normal SQL.

Assuming that the sequence is already 'complete' and x<sub>n+1</sub> can be derived from x<sub>n</sub>, such as when the dates are sequential and all present:

```
SELECT date -- the 1 on the day following the 0
FROM r curr
JOIN r prev
-- join each day with the previous day
ON curr.date = dateadd(d, 1, prev.date)
WHERE curr.indicator = 1
  AND prev.indicator = 0
```

YMMV on the ability of such a query to use indexes efficiently.

- If the sequence is not complete the same can be applied after making a delegate sequence which is well ordered and similarly 'complete'.
- This can also be done using [*correlated subqueries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), each selecting the indicator of the 'previous max', but.. uhg.

Comment: I think this one is more flexible.  This one works for indicators or any variable that I want to check for directional changes.

Comment: *`correlated`* sub-queries.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the terminology correction.. old patterns die hard.

Answer (score 2):

Joining the table against it self it quite generic, but most SQL Dialects now support Analytical Functions.  Ideally you could use `LAG()` but TeraData seems to try to support the absolute minimum of these, and so so they point you to use `SUM()`  combined with `rows preceding`.

In any regard, this method avoids a potentially costly join and effectively deals with gaps in the data, whilst making maximum use of indexes.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable   t
QUALIFY
  t.indicator
  <
  SUM(t.indicator) OVER (PARTITION BY t.somecolumn /* optional */
                             ORDER BY t.Date
                         ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                        )
```

`QUALIFY` is a bit TeraData specific, but slightly tidier than the alternative...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(t.indicator) OVER (PARTITION BY t.somecolumn /* optional */
                               ORDER BY t.Date
                           ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                          )
                            AS previous_indicator
  FROM
    yourTable   t
)
  lagged
WHERE
  lagged.indicator < lagged.previous_indicator
```

Comment: This should be the answer - it addresses the specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you mean that you want to determine whether any row having `1` as its `indicator` value has an earlier `Date` than a row in its group having `0` as its `indicator` value, you can identify groups with that characteristic by including the appropriate extreme dates in your aggregate results:

```
SELECT
  ...
  MAX(CASE indicator WHEN 0 THEN Date END) AS last_ind_0,
  MIN(CASE indicator WHEN 1 THEN Date END) AS first_ind_1,
  ...
```

You then test whether `first_ind_1` is less than `last_ind_0`, either in code or as another selection item.

Comment: This meets my creteria so it's a correct answer and I am selecting it as such.  What if, instead of an indicator, I am looking at a value to decrease from one date to the next.  My actual data isn't an indicator but IS an integer that I want to check for to see if it decreases so I chose a bad example here.